# How do I convert number to words while looping in LESS?

Tags: less

I am exploring a way to convert numbers in words while looping through LESS.

Right now I have following code

```
.margin(@n, @i:1) when (@i <= @n) {
  .space-@{i} {
    margin: 0rem+ @i ;
  }
  .space-@{i}-top {
    margin-top: 0rem + @i ;
  }
  .space-@{i}-bottom {
    margin-top: 0rem + @i ;
  }
  .margin(@n, (@i+1));
}

.margin(2);
```

Which produces:

```
.space-1 {
  margin: 1rem;
}
.space-1-top {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.space-1-bottom {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.space-2 {
  margin: 2rem;
}
.space-2-top {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.space-2-bottom {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

However, I wanted to achieve class names as `space-one` instead `space-1` and so on.

How do I utilize array in LESS? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`extract`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-extract) function. E.g.

```
@names:
    one,
    two,
    three,
    four,
    five;

.margin(3);
.margin(@i: 1) when (@i > 0) {
    .margin(@i - 1);
    @name: extract(@names, @i);
    .space-@{name} {
        margin: @i * 1rem;
    }
}
```